# StubbleOrg(mustache) configure date format

Tags: c#, .net-core, mustache

I want to replace `{{HiredAt}}` with seconds since Unix epoch, using [StubbleOrg](https://github.com/StubbleOrg). However, I cannot figure out how. I have read about lambda expressions and `AddValueGetter` but I can't seem to figure out how to use either. I cannot change my model, so it would need to be configured on the renderer if possible?

I unsuccessfully tried making a custom valuegetter, but I can't seem to understand the usage. I would like to be able to do something like: `{{HiredAt|DateTime.Unix}}`.

Currently I do (shortened) this (where contract has a DateTime called HiredAt:

```
var stubble = new StubbleBuilder().Build().Render("{{HiredAt}}", contract);
```

but this produces:

> "09-07-2019 22:00:00"

And I need it to be:

> "1562702400"

Comment: Any [mcve] maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried elaborating on the use.